# Autoscale stuck at 1, never see getSplitBacklogBytes() execute

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am creating a custom IO connector in Java that runs is streaming mode with 2.8.0 SDK.  It reads from a messaging queue for further pipeline processing, similar to JMS IO.  All works well except the auto-scaling does not seem to work.  The odd part for me is that I have implemented a getSplitBacklogBytes() method, but as far as the logs show, it is never executed.

I am testing with a modified wordcount example to test, executed with:

```
--runner=DataflowRunner --autoscalingAlgorithm=THROUGHPUT_BASED  --maxNumWorkers=4
```

The Pipeline options and logs seem to show that auto-scaling is being set up correctly.

```
PipelineOptions: Current Settings:
  autoscalingAlgorithm: THROUGHPUT_BASED
  maxNumWorkers: 4
  numWorkers: 0
```

Logs show:

```
20:50:54:977 .. [INFO] .. - 2019-01-08T20:50:40.937Z: Autoscaling is enabled for job 2019-01-08_12_50_40-3227727519433807139. The number of workers will be between 1 and 4.
20:50:54:991 .. [INFO] .. - 2019-01-08T20:50:42.943Z: Autoscaling: Enabled for job 2019-01-08_12_50_40-3227727519433807139 between 1 and 4 worker processes.
20:50:55:052 .. [INFO] .. - 2019-01-08T20:50:49.186Z: Generating 4 persistent disks which will allow autoscaling from 1 to 4 workers.
20:50:55:053 .. [INFO] .. - 2019-01-08T20:50:49.493Z: Starting 1 workers...
```

Is there anything else that needs to be done to enable this feature, or anything I might have done to inadvertently disable this feature?

Source code lives here:
https://github.com/SolaceLabs/solace-beam-integration/tree/development

Comment: Hi Ken! It's very cool that you are implementing a new source. Would you consider asking this question in the Apache Beam mailing list? user@beam.apache.org? - That way you could get Beam developers to help you with it (and later update the findings here on StackOverflow)

Comment: Thanks for your guidance.

Comment: Email to  user@beam.apache.org failed.  Is there a better mail list?

Comment: I guess you need to subscribe first before sending email. Can you try that?